# Python Turtle Graphics with Geometry Propogation

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, turtle-graphics, propagation

I am trying to make the window my turtle graphics run in have geometry propagation, but when I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle

tk=Tk()
tk.grid_propagate()
turtle.pd
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.mainloop()
```

I get two windows, one with geometry propagation and no graphics, and one with graphics and no propagation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How exactly do you expect `turtle` and `tk` to interact? Where did this come from?

Comment: I had turtle running in the tkinter graphics window.

Comment: @Veedrac: the [`turtle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#module-turtle) module is titled "turtle graphics for tk".

Comment: @martineau Thanks, that explains it. Even so, how would the modules interact? I've seen no evidence that they can.

Comment: @Veedrac: Well, one way is by using [`turtle.getcanvas()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.getcanvas) and then drawing on it with `tk.Canvas` methods.